# postfix transport maps not working correctly with lmtp

Tags: postfix

I am trying to get mailman 3 running with my existing postfix server on another host in the internet. I think I am quite far, but for some reason, postfix does not correctly send mails for mailman to the mailman host using lmtp.

I have created a map file `postfix_lmtp` with several entries in the following format:

```
test@example.com                       lmtp:[127.0.0.1]:8024
```

The LMTP server is up and running. (I connect to it using an SSH tunnel, that's why it's connecting using localhost.)

The file was also processed by `postmap` so that postfix can use it.

I have added this file to the following configuration options in `main.cf` (although not sure if all of them are really necessary...)

- virtual_alias_maps
- transport_maps
- local_recipient_maps

Postfix seems to acknowledge the information and process it, but for some reason it is still not working. This is what is shown in the log file:

```
Jan 21 xx:xx:xx myserver postfix/local[3180670]: xxxxxxxx: to=<"lmtp:[127.0.0.1]:8024"@myserver.example.com>, orig_to=<test@example.com>, relay=local, delay=0.51, delays=0.48/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "lmtp:[127.0.0.1]:8024")
```

It seems as if the destination `lmtp:[127.0.0.1]:8024` is not interpreted as a socket to connect to, but rather as a user name.

Any idea what could be wrong in my setup or how I could further debug?

Comment: [Show your config](https://serverfault.com/tags/postfix/info) - looks like you configured specified your transport map in with an alias map setting.